# R: merging data from two large dataframes with overlapping columns while prioritizing one over the other

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframes. In reality I want to merge an ''old'' database (size 2464x1231) and a ''new'' database (size 2385x868). I prioritize data from the new database over the old database, so only if data is missing in the new database I will take data from the old database.

I made an example of the data and specifically kept the same names for the columns per each dataframe:

```
patient_id <- c("example_1", "example_2", "example_5", "example_8", "example_9")
characteristic_1 <- c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) 
characteristic_2 <- c("Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate", NA, NA) 
characteristic_3 <- c(1, 2, NA, 2, 4)  
characteristic_4 <- c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA) 
characteristic_5 <- c("Yes","Yes", "No", NA, NA) 
old_database <- data.frame(patient_id, characteristic_1, characteristic_2, characteristic_3, characteristic_4, characteristic_5)

patient_id <- c("example_1", "example_2", "example_3", "example_5", "example_11")
characteristic_1 <- c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) 
characteristic_2 <- c("Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Slightly") 
characteristic_3 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4)  
characteristic_4 <- c(NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
characteristic_5 <- c("Yes","Yes", "Yes", "No", NA) 
new_database <- data.frame(patient_id, characteristic_1, characteristic_2, characteristic_3, characteristic_4, characteristic_5)
```

If I use:
merged_db <- merge(new_database, old_database, by = "patient_id", all = TRUE)

I get many matching columns twice, for example: characteristic_1.x and characteristic_1.y. I think this may not be the most ideal option.

PS. I also tried using chatGPT which gave additional:

```
for (col in colnames(merged_db)){
if (col != "patient_id"){
merged_db[col][!is.na(merged_db[col, paste0(col, ".y")])] <- merged_db[col, paste0(col, ".x     [!is.na(merged_db[col, paste0(col, ".y")])]
  }
}
```

I understand that chatGPT is trying to prioritize columns of one dataframe over the other, but it doesn't work.

I few comparable questions have been made previously but only in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically called an "update join". With `dplyr` we can use `rows_upsert` since you want to both update existing rows and insert new rows:

```
library(dplyr)
old_database %>% rows_upsert(new_database, by = "patient_id")
#   patient_id characteristic_1 characteristic_2 characteristic_3 characteristic_4
# 1  example_1             TRUE         Moderate                1               NA
# 2  example_2               NA           Severe                2            FALSE
# 3  example_5            FALSE         Moderate               NA            FALSE
# 4  example_8            FALSE             <NA>                2            FALSE
# 5  example_9             TRUE             <NA>                4               NA
# 6  example_3            FALSE         Moderate                3             TRUE
# 7 example_11            FALSE         Slightly                4             TRUE
#   characteristic_5
# 1              Yes
# 2              Yes
# 3               No
# 4             <NA>
# 5             <NA>
# 6              Yes
# 7             <NA>
```

See `?rows_upsert` for more details and similar functions. You might also be interested in `rows_patch` which only updates `NA` values... can't really tell without the desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much. And what if variables/columns do not 100% overlap. So when the old_database has columns that do not exist in the new_database and vice versa. Because when I use rows_upset I get an error: ''All columns in `y` must exist in `x`''

Comment: I think you can do a upsert with the overlapping columns followed by a regular join to add the new columns. It's a bit of a pain, but seems to be the way things need to work with `rows_upsert`.

Comment: Perhaps more simply you could initialize the columns to `NA`, then the upsert should work as intended. `old_database[setdiff(names(new_database, old_database)] = list(NA)`, followed by `rows_upsert(old_database, new_database, by = ...)`.